# How to do map for two index sphinx

Tags: python, indexing, sphinx

I have an index say 'CourtCase' and i have an other index 'defendant'.
I DB defendant table has a FK to CourtCase Table So i can get the courtCase information per defendant.I have  Multi Database System So Each county will be saved in different indexer

CourtCase indexer format :

```
CA_1_C_I__Index
CA_2_C_II__Index
```

Defendant Index :

```
CA_1_D_I_Index
CA_2_D_II_Index
```

But in indexer i need to display all CourtCase along with defendant information. How can i do that. I am new in Sphinx, i request to answer in a simple way.

Answer (score 1):

In databases you are taught to denormalize.

With sphinx indexes you should normalize. Put everything in one big index. Duplicating data is not a problem.

For example could just have a Defendant index. You should join in the Case table when building the index, so the index contains the case and defentant data together.

---

A single sphinx 'index' can contain multiple 'source', so each source can connect to a different physical database (in case of multiple servers)

-or-

Can have multiple sphinx indexes on different servers (eg one sphinx index per database), each creating their own contained index from tables on that database. - Then use a sphinx distributed index, to unify the seperate indexes into one virtual one.

Comment: i have a small doubt. In tha above Example, i have two index for court case 1) CA_1_C_I__Index 2)CA_2_C_II__Index . While querying time i got say 3 record . How i get to know which source returns the data 1 , 2 and 3.

Comment: only jsut found the tweets. Can just add unique attribute to the indexes, so will know by looking at that attribute. Or as the IDs must be unique, can perhaps deduce the index from that.